# Bigquery to S3 File upload using Python: raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract a data from BQ and save it to CSV and then upload it to s3, but I'm having error with the uploading to s3. This is the error I get when I run the script:

```
raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')
```

If you can please help me solve this issue, I'm new to Python and AWS. Thank you

Script is:

```
    rows_df = query_job.result().to_dataframe() 
    file_csv = rows_df.to_csv(s3_filename, sep='|', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    s3.upload_file(file_csv, s3_bucket, file_csv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the arguments passed to `s3.upload_file` like so:

```
s3.upload_file(s3_filename, s3_bucket, s3_filename)
```

The `to_csv` writes the dataframe to a local file at path `s3_filename` and `file_csv` is `None`. Alternatively, if your dataframe is small enough to be held in memory, the following should do the trick:

```
import io
data = rows_df.to_csv(sep='|', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
data_buffer = io.BytesIO(data)
s3.upload_fileobj(data_buffer, s3_bucket, s3_filename)
```

Comment: whats the difference between upload_file and upload_fileobj? I tried running the script with your suggestion and it return the error ValueError: Fileobj must implement read.

Comment: Here's a SO answer to that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336902/what-is-the-difference-between-s3-client-upload-file-and-s3-client-upload-file I've updated the second code example, the data_buffer is now an file-like object that upload_fileobj accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), `to_csv` returns `None` when `path_or_buf` is specified. However, [`upload_file`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) needs a filename and a S3 key in its first and third argument respectively. Therefore, something like this could make this work.

```
s3.upload_file(s3_filename, s3_bucket, s3_filename)
```